# Trouble using printf %f %n with a double, then adding a string?

Tags: java, printf

I'm trying to make it so that a list of numbers, with 6 dedicated characters, and two 2 decimal figures appears, followed by a "|".

```
for (int c = 1; c < Config.MAX_VALUE; c++)
        System.out.printf("%6.2f %n",(double)c + "|");
```

I'm having trouble adding the "|" and get the error

"Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String"

How might I format it properly?

Comment: The types in the format have to match the types of the arguments you give it.

Answer (score 5):

Move the `|` character to the format string, not to the format arguments.  It looks like you want

```
 System.out.printf("%6.2f| %n",(double)c);
```

`%f` only knows how to format number types, and you're passing it a `String` from converting `c` to a `double`, then to a `String`, and then adding a `|` to the end.  That gives you a `String`, which `%f` doesn't know how to format.